# Use rollapplyr in parallel computing

Tags: r

I need to do a 36-month rolling regression for each column and get the intercept for each regression. There are about 100 rows and 9000 columns. The original code took 10 hours to run in my laptop. I want to use parallel computing to reduce running time, but it returns error. Below is my code

```
library(parallel)
library(zoo)

    no_cores <- detectCores()-1
    c1 <- makeCluster(no_cores)

    z <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
        getCoef <- function(z, lhs, rhs){
          if(all(is.na(z[,lhs]))) NA
          else coef(lm(paste(lhs, "~", rhs), z))["(Intercept)"] 
        }

        roll <- function(z, lhs, rhs = "A + B + C + D + E") {
          rollapplyr(z, 36, getCoef, by.column = FALSE, coredata = FALSE, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs)
        }

        ynames <- colnames(df)[2:8785]
        tm1 <- system.time(
          L_rr <- ParLapply(c1, ynames, roll, z = z)
          )
```

The error that I got is :

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "rollapplyr"
```

In other words, I guess similar to ParLapply being similar to lapply in a parallel computing setting, there is a function equivalent rollapplyr. I wonder what it is. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
library(parallel)
library(zoo)

no_cores <- detectCores()-1
c1 <- makeCluster(no_cores)

clusterEvalQ(c1, {
    library(zoo)
    z <- read.zoo(df, FUN = as.yearmon, format = "%m/%d/%Y")
    getCoef <- function(z, lhs, rhs){
                if(all(is.na(z[,lhs]))) NA
                else coef(lm(paste(lhs, "~", rhs), z))["(Intercept)"] 
    }

    roll <- function(z, lhs, rhs = "A + B + C + D + E") {
                rollapplyr(z, 36, getCoef, by.column = FALSE, coredata = FALSE, lhs = lhs, rhs = rhs)
    }

    ynames <- colnames(df)[2:8785]
})

tm1 <- system.time(
            L_rr <- ParLapply(c1, ynames, roll, z = z)
        )
stopCluster(c1)
```

You need to setup your parallel worker like you would your parent environment. I did this by embedding your functions, libraries, data in `clusterEvalQ(cl, {..}`. Make sure to kill your cluster after you're done.

Let me know if it doesn't work

Comment: Thank you. When I run the code, it shows a notification: Error in checkForRemoteErrors(lapply(cl, recvResult)) : 
  3 nodes produced errors; first error: object 'rr' not found. The code is still running though.

Comment: `rr` is an object, function, package that you're using in parallel but haven't cloned to each worker. Do you have other sections of code you're running that you haven't shown?

Comment: Oh, sorry rr is actually df (shown in the code above). It should have been created in my workspace.

Comment: The code is still running. I will accept it once it finishes running. Thanks!